# javascript replace function not returning new value

Tags: javascript, lodash

The task is simple. I wrote a function that is expected to replace the string from an identifier and array of object().

```
var replacer = function(original, replacement) {
     console.log(replacement)
        _.each(replacement, (value, key) => {
            original =  original.replace('${' + key+'}', value)
        });
        return original;    
}

console.clear();


var asString = "This is my email ${email} & ${mobile}";
var replacement = {"email":"abcd@yahoo.co.in", "mobile":"999999999"}
asString = replacer(asString, replacement);
console.log(asString) // Here i am getting it properly replaced


var replacement ={"email":"xyz@yahoo.co.in", "mobile":"0000000"}
asString2 = replacer(asString, replacement);
console.log(asString2) // Here i am still getting old value not new value
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1gc9xka8/

if you check the update one,
http://jsfiddle.net/1gc9xka8/1

I even changed the variable but still i get the old value.

Kindly advise what is wrong here.

Comment: Didnt test out your code but you dont need to reassign original...original.replace will mutate original

Comment: Without lodash, vanilla  : `Object.keys(replacement).reduce((result, current) => result.replace("${" + current + "}", replacement[current]) , asString )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the replaced string instead of original string

```js
var replacer = function(original, replacement) {
  console.log(replacement)
  _.each(replacement, (value, key) => {
    original = original.replace('${' + key + '}', value)
  });
  return original;
}

console.clear();
var asString = "This is my email ${email} & ${mobile}";
var replacement1 = {
  "email": "abcd@yahoo.co.in",
  "mobile": "999999999"
};
var asStringReplacement1 = replacer(asString, replacement1);
console.log(asStringReplacement1);
var replacement2 = {
  "email": "xyz@yahoo.co.in",
  "mobile": "0000000"
};
var asStringReplacement2 = replacer(asString, replacement2);
console.log(asStringReplacement2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```